# How to select null when the record does not exist with UNION ALL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, null

I have a book in excel with records of hundreds of students, each of them has an identification number followed by first and last names.

I need to extract more information such as date of birth, gender, etc. For this I have a *Student* table where all the information I require is stored (therefore I do not need any with JOIN with other tables), so I thought about doing rune function in excel that concatenates the query followed by a UNION:

```
=CONCATENAR("SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='";A1;"') AS T UNION ALL")
```

However, the identification numbers may be outdated so the records are incomplete (if I do the query with 200 records they can leave 190), they are small differences but I need to do this task several times then, what I want is this:

```
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
| Std_Identification | Std_Gender | Std_BirthDate |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|      34998545      |      0     |   12/05/1997  |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|      12443334      |     NULL   |      NULL     |  <- This record NOT exists in the table Student
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|      39405443      |      1     |   21/09/1980  |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
```

I tried this with the following query, but I still do not succeed:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='34998545') AS T UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='12443334') AS T UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='39405443') AS T
```

But the result was:

```
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
| Std_Identification | Std_Gender | Std_BirthDate |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|      34998545      |      0     |   12/05/1997  |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
|      39405443      |      1     |   21/09/1980  |
+--------------------+------------+---------------+
```

- How can I make the SELECT UNION display a NULL instead of a blank
  when the record does not exist?
- Is it possible to do the same but when I require a JOIN with several
  tables? Let's say that I need to extract the number of subjects that
  is in another table *X* (therefore due to make a JOIN between the
  table *Student* and table *X*), but not all students have code or a
  record to relate it to that table *X*

Comment: try to use [(select 34998545 ID ) left join Std_identification]

Answer (score 0):

just assign the values you need to the related  columns

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate 
        FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='34998545') AS T UNION ALL
SELECT  '12443334', NULL, NULL  UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Std_Identification, Std_Gender, Std_BirthDate 
        FROM Student WHERE Std_Identification='39405443') AS T
```

Or you could use a left join on the same table applying teh filter in on condition ..  in this way if you have 200  student you retrive ever 200 rows include the rows for not matching filter

```
select distinct a.Std_Identification 
from Student a
left join stundent b on a.Std_Identification = b.Std_Identification 
        AND b.Std_Gender = 'M'
```

Comment: Oh no, I think I did not understand well :p I have the list of students, but I do not know who specifically exist or not in the table, that is why I decided to consult all with a SELECT UNION and I realized that if I consult the 200 of them I get 190), what I want is to show me the missing students (rows in NULL as in the example of '12443334') in the same order that I consulted them and then copy and paste the result in the Excel book without have to move anything

Comment: This does not work my friend :'(, it seems that the best way to do this is to organize the identification documents from the smallest to the largest Excel file, then on another sheet with the same information organized search the documents in the database as I am currently doing , after having the result that the SSMS sends me, I have to filter duplicate records in the column of the documents, and the remaining records (not duplicates) look for them manually, after that organize the records from least to greatest and with some I will have completed my goal.

Comment: i don't understand you comment .is. to complex .. i'm not in your code processing so i can't undestand what you are doing .. i'm based only on the sample you provided  in your question above.

Answer (score 0):

I had this question a long time ago, the problem was that I needed data that was a SQL Server database but from the identification of a student, the order of the data in Excel was very important because I needed to paste the new data on the spreadsheet.

Some data did not exist (because the identification was not in the database) therefore I could not omit it and for this I was using SELECT UNION, this caused that in the end it returned less rows.

The simplest solution I found at that time was to create a formula in the spreadsheet (Excel) per row to insert the rows into a temporary table:

```
=CONCATENAR("INSERT INTO @TempTable(Id) VALUES('";A1;"');")
```

Then make an OUTER APPLY, it is similar to a LEFT JOIN combined with a TOP 1, this allows me to have the most updated record because in the table there can be more than one record with the same identification:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE ( Id VARCHAR(20) NULL );

// paste your inserts into from Excel

SELECT T.Id, SS.Std_Identification, SS.Std_Gender, SS.Std_BirthDate 
FROM @TempTable T
OUTER APPLY
( 
    SELECT TOP 1 S.Std_Identification, S.Std_Gender, S.Std_BirthDate 
    FROM Student S 
    WHERE S.Std_Identification = T.Id
    ORDER BY S.CreationDate DESC 
) AS SS
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,

1)Create a temp table on the data base with one column studentid.

2)Write INSERT INTO temptable VALUES ("A1") and copy the INSERT formula to all rows.This way ,you can create an INSERT INTO script with all the ids.

3) Left join your temp table to student table and all the records that are not in the student table will be displayed NULL.Row_Number() can be used to filter out the duplicated according to the criteria.

Edit 1:

I could not reply to your comment so I am making an edit here.

APPLY can be used too.
If you want to use the LEFT JOIN ,Row_number() can be used to filter out the dupes based on date

```
SELECT T.Id, SS.Std_Identification, SS.Std_Gender, SS.Std_BirthDate
FROM
@TempTable T
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
   S.Std_Identification, S.Std_Gender, S.Std_BirthDate,ROW_NUMBER() OVER       
   (PARTITION BY S.Std_Identification ORDER BY S.CreationDate DESC ) AS RN
  )S
 ON
 T.Id=S S.Std_Identification
 WHERE S.RN=1
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN can also be useful, although in my case I had records with the same Id in the Students table, when doing LEFT JOIN I would join all the rows with that Identifier when I really wanted a single record (the most recent), so I use OUTER APPLY with a sort by date